# Watermark 2000+ images at once?

Tags: php

I have a image hosting service and people upload offline (they upload to another computer like a station without internet access) and then we sync the images (they aren't watermarked at this stage) and they are not approved at this point.

There is an admin area where the user would go to approve an image, and we will apply the watermark at this stage.

I am wondering what method would be best to watermark 2000ish images using PHP (at a time). Would creating a system daemon and waiting for a response a good idea or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performing such tasks on such a high number of files is not a good idea with php, at least when you plan to execute that script via HTTP. The reason for that is the timeout of a php script, which is usually 30s (and shouldn't be set too high).

The best option to solve such things is to create a script or daemon that runs directly on the server and converts any new image automatically (or after being told so). So it will continue to run even when the current php script has finished. The background process could then for example update statistics into a database which the php script can fetch to get information about the process.

Another way, I personally use for the thumbnail generation of a private gallery, is to split the high number of tasks into smaller jobs that can be easily worked with in the 30s limit. In my case, I limit it to 50 pictures per execution (it could probably handle a lot more, but I want to be safe). So basically I call my script, it gets the first 50 not-already-completed filenames from a database, does its thing on each file and returns. And then I simply click F5 to let the script do the next 50 files. With ~2000 images, it would probably be wise to automate the F5-hitting, for example by simply putting a javascript on the page that refreshes it after it loaded completely.

If you have the possibilites to go with the first option, do that, but I have found my second option to be quite useful for shared hosting (which is where I use it currently).

Comment: What may be a better language? I have PHP, Perl, RoR?

Comment: @Steven: Well, it doesn't really matter what language it is. When you execute any script via HTTP and that script starts to work off 2k images sequentially, it will take a long time and the webserver will most likely interrupt the response before the script has finished. If you plan to use a background process, it doesn't matter at all what language you use, you could use a native program that does the job or a bash script that uses many little tools to do the job.

Comment: The 30 second `max_execution_time` only applies when PHP is called through a web server (from a browser). If there's a server-side PHP script run directly (command line), there is no limit by default.

Comment: @Wiseguy: That's why I referred to it as “called via HTTP”, i.e. through the webserver. Of course the script can run on a separate process the way it likes, but both (the timeout and the CLI calling) applies to any other language..

Comment: Agreed. I was just clarifying for others' sake that PHP isn't _always_ subject to an execution time limit, especially since others are suggesting the use of cronjobs (where PHP would run without this limit).

Answer (score 1):

Set up a script in cron, and do it in the background.

Comment: In small increments (not all at once). You want to make sure your cron's do not overlap, i.e., you do not have 2 or more seperate instances running at the same time. You either need to set some kind of flag to indicate your processing (i.e., create a text file, check if it exists to determine if it's locked, then delete it when your down processing) -- or use a database. But really, PHP is not the ideal language for batch image processing.

Comment: // offtopic Hey @John, I didn't know you were on SO

Comment: What may be a better language? I have PHP, Perl, RoR?

Comment: @Jonah Just got on a couple weeks ago :D Small world!

Comment: @Steven ROR, since it supports multi-threading (which is what I was refering to in regards to choosing a better language)

Answer (score 0):

The best thing would be to run a Cron job/daemon in the background.  But, instead of a PHP script, just use a simple bash script with ImageMagick.  That is, if you don't have to access a database or anything to get the images.

If you *do* need to access a database, use PHP, but call [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/shell-exec) to run the bash script on the correct images.  If you're on a Windows server, you'd obviously use a batch script instead.